# Generalisation of function in Java

Tags: java, processing, generalization

How can I generalize pendulumManagement() to take as arguments the names of the functions to fire and the boolean to decide on? I'm using java and processing library.

```java
void pendulumManagement()
{
  if (pendul) {
    singlePendulumManagement();
  } else {
    dublePendulumManagement();
  }
}
```

Comment: Declare it as `void pendulumManagement(final Runnable onTrue, final Runnable onFalse) { if ( pendul ) { onTrue.run(); } else { onFalse.run(); } }` and then call it like `pendulumManagement(this::singlePendulumManagement, this::doublePendulumManagement)`.

Comment: @fluffy  Your method doesn't work. I have those errors: https://imgur.com/a/qTqJ4O2

Comment: _Your_ method does not work. Did you read what I commented?

Comment: I did what you wrote, but it doesn't work.

Comment: So you're stuck in a pre-Java 8. Sure, it cannot work for you. Nevermind.

Comment: I believe it's not impossible to reference a method in Processing, but I wouldn't suggest it to a beginner. This sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Do you really need to pass a method as a parameter or just to know which pendulum method you are supposed to call in the `pendulumManagement()` method?

Comment: I have this function in my program: https://pastebin.com/5DAAN6gq, and there I have few different ifs: ```if (pendul)
    {
      singlePendulumManagement();
    } else 
    {
      dublePendulumManagement();
    }``` which are almost the same and I want to boil it down to one function with three arguments.

Comment: @Raflow I get it now. Processing 3 won't be able to do this, but theoretically you could use Processing as a library in another java IDE and do it the way fluffy suggested. [Processing 4 is still in alpha](https://github.com/processing/processing4) and will support java 11.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to use a [flag argument](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html). From that article:

> A flag argument is a kind of function argument that tells the function to carry out a different operation depending on its value.
>
> [...]
>
> My general reaction to flag arguments is to avoid them. Rather than use a flag argument, I prefer to define separate methods.
>
> [...]
>
> My reasoning here is that the separate methods communicate more clearly what my intention is when I make the call.

My advice would be to think about that design choice again and reconsider if you actually *should* do it that way. The article mentioned above has more details about cases like the one that you describe.

Comment: This is how my project looks like: https://github.com/Rafhub69/Everythig . How would you go about it?

Comment: This is probably the way to go, depending on OP's real objective (+1). I believe that a code snippet would make this answer easier to understand for OP, which may lack the experience to apply it thoroughly.

Comment: Not a XY problem, I see. This isn't going to be easy if you really want it.

Answer (score 0):

While I like generalization as a general rule, I don't think that your program would benefit from it in this case. Yet I too feel the appeal of shortening these to one-liners.

You can still write them as one-liners and get a similar result, like this:

```
if (pendul) { singlePendulumManagement(); } else { dublePendulumManagement(); }
```

But the issue is that if you use auto-format it'll revert to several lines. Another option would be to use the ternary assignment operator '?', but for this to work you would need your methods to have a return type and use it to assign a value, which would be bad practice if unneeded. Still, here's how it *would* be done with a simple example:

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(255);

  boolean isRect = true;
  boolean whatever;
  
  whatever = isRect ? drawRectangle() : drawCircle();
  isRect = false;
  whatever = isRect ? drawRectangle() : drawCircle();
}

void draw() {
}

boolean drawRectangle() {
  rect(100, 100, 200, 100);
  return true;
}

boolean drawCircle() {
  circle(600, 300, 100);
  return true;
}
```

In this example, the `whatever` boolean has no real purpose, and the method's return either, which is why I dislike the idea, but if your methods had return types you could realistically use this trick to make your calls look like this:

```
boolean whatever;
switch(mode) {
case 1: //1 - gravitation
  whatever = field ? centralFieldManagement() : homogeneousFieldManagement();
  break;
case 2: //2 - pendulum
  whatever = pendul ? singlePendulumManagement() : dublePendulumManagement();
  break;
// etc etc..
}
```

Which, as I said, isn't great. If you don't use the auto-format at all, using the first form (to write the if on one line) would not only do the trick but also isn't much different from your initial idea in term of lines, characters and number of arguments.

Good luck!